# Whole Monitor Flicker When No Movement, First Movement, and on Terminal

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, laptop, monitor, flicker

I already using Xubuntu for 5 months and so far so good. But today, I changed my LCD because the old one is broken. At log screen, it looks fine but when I log in and let it sit for approx. 5 secs without any interaction (mouse movement/typing) it start to flick (whole monitor turn black [sometimes green], then turn on again). Then, if I start move the mouse/typing, it flick one more. It also flick when I using Terminal and run some commands, eg. when I try to install/upgrade package and when it's unpacking things.

Here are some additional information:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"

Linux depimomo-X555LAB 4.8.0-58-generic #63~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 18:08:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1616] (rev 09)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [1043:19ad]
Kernel driver in use: i915

DESKTOP_SESSION=xubuntu
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=xubuntu
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=XFCE

*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:48 memory:a9000000-a9ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

What I already try is reduce the refresh rate from 60 to 39.9, run this command:

```
sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

but it's responded with "Package 'xserver-xorg-video-intel' is not installed, so not removed 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.". I also try to fasten the flex cable and even try other new LCD. Oh in addition, the screen is work fine in Windows 10 (I dual boot my laptop). I try to disable hardware acceleration but I don't find the option in the settings or via command, besides I read that turn it off can cause bad effect on battery. My laptop type is Asus X555L. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Edit: already try to reduce resolution to 1024x768, no effect. Then I revert it to 1366x768 and it's still flickering. Also try to boot my laptop from USB with linux mint, no luck.